# Assembly program to find all divisors of an integer

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am trying to write a program that reads in an integer and finds all divisors of that integer (up to but not including the integer). After finding a divisor it is pushed on to the stack and at the end the divisors should be printed in reverse order.

This is the code I currently have:

```
; global and external declarations

global _main
extern  read_int, print_int, print_string
extern  read_char, print_char, print_nl

segment .data
prompt01 db 10, "Enter an integer: ",0
out01 db "Divisors: ",0

segment .bss
a resd 1

segment .text

_main:

enter   0,0 ; setup routine
pusha

; prompt for number
mov eax, prompt01   ; prompt for a
call print_string

call read_int       ; input a
mov [a], eax        ; move from eax to a
xor ecx, ecx        ; zero out ecx register


; do the division
mov ebx, 1      ; divisor in ebx
L1: mov eax, [a]        ; dividend in eax
cdq         ; sign extend eax to edx:eax pair
div ebx         ; divide - quotient in eax, remainder in edx
; if edx is 0, push on stack
cmp edx, 0
je L2
jmp L3
 ; if remainder was zero, push on to stack
L2: push edx
inc ecx         ; increment counter loop
L3: inc ebx         ; increment divisor
cmp ebx, eax        ; check if ebx = eax
je out
jmp L1

; print out everything in the stack
out:    mov eax, out01
call print_string

jcxz done
L4: pop edx
call print_int
call print_nl
loop L4

done:   popa        ; return routine
mov eax, 0
leave
ret
```

The expected output is something similar to this:

```
Enter an integer: 210
Divisors:
105
70
42
35
30
21
15
14
10
7
6
5
3
2
1
```

But I actually get this:

```
Enter an integer: 210
Divisors: 4210712
4210712
4210712
4210712
4210712
4210712
4210712
4210712
```

Since the Intel 80x86 has a division operation, I'm using DIV to divide my numbers and using the CDQ command to sign extend eax to the edx:eax pair.

I think the issue is occurring during the division since something is being pushed onto the stack (even though it isn't the correct thing). Any ideas for where this could be going wrong?

Comment: Make sure your `call print_int` expects argument in `edx`. I guess you will need `pop eax` instead of `pop edx`.

Comment: Use `xor edx,edx` to zero-extend into EDX:EAX before unsigned `div`.  Only use `cdq` with `idiv` to sign-extend the dividend, or if you're optimizing for code-size and know the the top bit of EAX is always 0.  Shouldn't matter for small numbers, though.

Comment: Related: [Checking if a number is prime in NASM Win64 Assembly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/204902) shows how you can keep more values in registers in a trial-division loop.  But since you want to print all possible divisors instead of stopping at the first one, some of the optimizations can't work.

Comment: I found a solution...I was pushing edx (as opposed to ebx) onto the stack and I was attempting to pop edx (as opposed to eax) off of the stack and print it.